# showing frequency a certain way

Tags: python

I can't get my solution to calculate the frequency and output it in a certain way

```
Number_of_Elements = int(input("Enter number of intergers to be stored in the list: "))
print("Input", Number_of_Elements, "elements in the list: ")

for i in range(Number_of_Elements):
    data = int(input("Element -" + str(i) + " : "))
    Elements_List.append(data)
all_freq = {} 

for i in Elements_List: 
    if i in all_freq: 
        all_freq[i] += 1
    else: 
        all_freq[i] = 1

print ("The frequency of all elements of the list :\n "+  str(all_freq))
```

I need the frequency to to look like this in the output:

(a number) occurs (x) times

and keep going until it tells us all the different numbers that were input and how many times they occurred

Answer (score 0):

```
Number_of_Elements = int(input("Enter number of intergers to be stored in the list: "))
print("Input", Number_of_Elements, "elements in the list: ")
Elements_List = []
for i in range(Number_of_Elements):
    data = int(input("Element -" + str(i) + " : "))
    Elements_List.append(data)
all_freq = {} 

for i in Elements_List: 
    if i in all_freq: 
        all_freq[i] += 1
    else: 
        all_freq[i] = 1

print ("The frequency of all elements of the list :\n "+  str(all_freq))
for a_number, x in all_freq.items(): print(f"({a_number}) occurs {x} times")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Number_of_Elements = int(input("Enter number of intergers to be stored in the list: "))
print("Input", Number_of_Elements, "elements in the list: ")

Elements_List = []
for i in range(Number_of_Elements):
    data = int(input("Element -" + str(i) + " : "))
    Elements_List.append(data)
all_freq = {} 

for i in Elements_List: 
    if i in all_freq: 
        all_freq[i] += 1
    else: 
        all_freq[i] = 1

for key in all_freq:
  print(str(key) + " occurs " + str(all_freq[key]) + " times")
```